# Get the height of the Snackbar in Xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a `ListView` shown in the screen and there is a `Snackbar` which is shown indefinitely. The last element of the `ListView` is getting covered partially because of the `Snackbar`.

I am trying to get the height of the Snackbar and give it as a bottom margin programmatically to the ListView.

```
Snackbar snackbar = 
Snackbar.Make(_refresher,"message",Snackbar.LengthIndefinite);

snackbar.Show();
View snackbarView = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout)snackbar.View;
int h = snackbarView.MeasuredHeightAndState;
```

But the height of the Snackbar is always 0.
I also tried `snackbarView.Height` and `snackbarView.MinimumHeight`, but it always returns 0.

Can anybody help me solving this issue?

Comment: did you tried before show `int h=snackbar.View.Height`

Comment: Have u tried this `snackbar.View.GetHeight();`

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki Doesnot work.

Comment: @Arvindraja View doesn't have a GetHeight() method in xamarin.android

Comment: `MeasuredHeightAndState` is definitely not what you want. You want just `Height`, but it will be 0 until that `View` gets laid out. You can simply `Post()` a `Runnable` to the `Snackbar`'s `View`, and get the `Height` in that, as the `View` will have been laid out by the time that queued `Runnable` executes. In Xamarin, I _think_ it would be something like `snackbarView.Post(()=>{ int height = snackbarView.Height; ... });`. I'm not very familiar with the syntax.

Comment: `snackbar.View.Post(() => 
{

int h=snackbar.View.Height();
Log.Error ("Height", "Height"+h);

});` try this

Answer (score 1):

i am not familiar with xamarin but i work with snakbar many times so may this work like this

You need to use view.post because height property only becomes available after the view is inflated/run

Ref : https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.View/

Ref : https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.Lang.IRunnable/

```
snackbar.View.Post(() => 
{

int h=snackbar.View.Height();
Log.Error ("Height", "Height"+h);

});
```

**i hope it helps**